Why is the `unicode-show` package necessary?
I'm using the unicode-show package to make a passing hspec test:
code:
...(show . Data.List.NonEmpty.head $ infiles2, outFile2) `shouldBe` ("\"/foo/bar/baz - ：.ogg\"", outFile1))...

       expected: ("\"/foo/bar/baz - ：.ogg\"", "/foo/bar/fee.m4a")
        but got: ("\"/foo/bar/baz - \\65306.ogg\"", "/foo/bar/fee.m4a")

but then this code passes:
...(Text.Show.Unicode.ushow . Data.List.NonEmpty.head $ infiles2, outFile2) `shouldBe` ("\"/foo/bar/baz - ：.ogg\"", outFile1))...

Test suite spec: RUNNING...
.........
Finished in 0.0115 seconds
9 examples, 0 failures, 2 pending
Test suite spec: PASS

Why is this necessary? Why doesn't show do the right thing here?

Why do you use show in the first place?

Good question, I have to build up a string to be used to create a CmdSpec in the program. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.24.0/docs/System-Process.html#t:CmdSpec

@Cheercheeo: but what is infiles2 here, what is its type?

It is the same type as Data.List.NonEmpty.head infiles2. It is irrelevant to the question at hand.
edit: Data.List.NonEmpty.head infiles2 is the same type as outfile2

I don't think it is irrelevant. If it is a String, Text, or IsString type, that is also an instance of Eq, you can just use OverloadedStrings and then check the content itself, without any show. In fact show only will trigger more false negatives.

I believe your intuition is incorrect on all accounts, but I'm interested in being proven wrong: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-0.9.5/docs/Path-Posix.html#t:Path

construct a path, for example as $(mkAbsFile "/foo/bar/baz - \65306.ogg"), this will also check that the path is absolute, and points to a file, so making sure the type and the possible different parameters match.

The implementors of show @String had two design goals: 1. produce valid Haskell code that means the same thing as the input that 2. uses only 7-bit clean ASCII. (Remember, Haskell was designed back in the 90s-ish! We were still in the dark ages where not all software supported Unicode yet, notably terminals and email clients.) So all codepoints above 127 get escaped.

You should not use show to check the equivalence of two strings. Indeed, if you use:
"/foo/bar/baz - ：.ogg" == "/foo/bar/baz - \65306.ogg"

this returns True, because both strings contain 20 characters, and each character is the same. So your tests can (probably) work with:
(Data.List.NonEmpty.head infiles2, outFile2) `shouldBe` ($(mkAbsFile "/foo/bar/baz - \65306.ogg"), outFile1))
But you use show here. What does show :: Show a => a -> String function [Hackage]? It is usually used to convert an object a into a string that is an string that contains code to construct a. So for an Int like 5, it produces "5", if you would write 5 in the terminal, then you construct the Int 5.
But there are multiple ways to construct 5, for example 1 + 4 is 5 as well, but "5" and "1 + 4" are not the same String. These are two expressions that produce 5, but when checking at the string level, these are different strings.
This is thus what show for a string will do, it will produce a string like "\"/foo/bar/baz - \\65306.ogg\"" with as content "/foo/bar/baz - \65306.ogg", notice that this string contains 27 characters. Indeed, the special colon character is escaped as \65306, which contains six characters, as well as the quote characters as \", so two characters per quote.
The unicode characters do not have to be escaped per se, so if the escaping is done differently, you get two different results, and thus the strings are different, and thus the test fails.
Checking the equivalence of the two shows is thus not guaranteed to work, since two expressions can construct the same value, but with a different expression. In fact ushow will not work correctly either, indeed if you would have used:
(Text.Show.Unicode.ushow . Data.List.NonEmpty.head $ infiles2, outFile2) `shouldBe` ("\"/foo/bar/baz - \\65306.ogg\"", outFile1))
that would have failed exactly where show would have worked.
So as a rule of thumb: don't use show to check equivalence of two values. Try to check with the (==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool on the real values. Usually using the result of show is prone to error: one has to follow the exact rules the show (or ushow) uses to encode the value into a string, and it might be subject to (pseudo) randomness, for example in the case of hashsets.

I don't know if you're misunderstanding the question or you don't care but this doesn't address the thrust of the question.

@cheecheeo: I think it does. It is the same as testing show 5 `shouldBe` "1+4". The right side would be a correct expression to generate 5, but show doesn't do it that way, it generates a string with one character: 5, it thus does not perform semantical interpretation of the expression.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79139282/why-is-the-unicode-show-package-necessary/79139295#comment139547443_79139282 as to why string comparison is being used in this test.

@cheecheeo: if it is indeed a Path Abs File, you can use a Template Haskell/Quasiquoter to construct the value, so you don't need to show/ushow to make it an accessible format. But I had the idea it was not relevant?
